# How to connect Multiple gateways to send Sms

Tags: sms, smpp, jsmpp

Can any one tell me how to connect multiple gateways to send Sms, actually I started SMPP_v3.4, first for the testing purpose I used **Logica SMPPSim** for testing the simple delivery process it works fine, but when I tried to connect multiple gateways making both gateways active, only second gateway is submitting the records which or in Queue. I googled so much no luck.

Comment: Can you share your code (or at least an outline of if)? It will give some more context.

Comment: Wahid i cannot share code here,actually that application is developed by spring,which will get gateway configuration from database,when i run main method in my application it will bind to SMPPsim batch file and read records from Queue,if telco is in active state it will submit all the messages,up to now every thing is ok for one gateway,i tried to send to multiple gateways where i changed port in smppsim.properties,but i am only able to send from one gateway.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two apparent strategies to drain a queue:

- On a single sender thread, apply round-robin among the outgoing gateways.
- Let individual threads own a gateway, drain messages from the queue and send them.

You may have to change the code to achieve this.

Comment: you are right wahid,when i run both gateway batch files ,suppose if am reading 2 records 2records are in Queue table and same 2 records are showing in success table,when i deactive one gateway another gateway messages are delivering to success table,i am new to SMS ,can u please elaborate your answer wahid

Comment: Referring to your first comment: (1) I am assuming you are running the com.logica.smpp.test.SMPPTest which uses smpptest.cfg. From the looks of it, it seems to me it only can handle one SMSC via default configuration. I think it's time to get your hands dirty. You can use certainly use logica library and achieve whatever you need to do; my answer tried to reflect that.  (2) Without seeing, it's quite difficult to address your problem. Can you share your code that contains main() method?

Comment: Well, the SMSServerImpl is not doing nothing other than creating the context. It must be one of the beans that's reading from your queue and sending them. ...  systemConfiguration ca provide config data for one SMSC only. Think along these lines - (1) Are you sure you have two sender configured? (2) Do you have active threads driving those sender? (3) Is your SMSC configured to accept more than one connection using the same port/username/password combination? ... I cannot offer anything without seeing the full code at this point. Consider creating a simpler version of the code and post here.

Comment: I cannot show you full code here wahid,i will try my level best to solve this, if possible please mail me,so that you can guide me,have you ever tried multiple gateways to send sms,not only SMPPsim ,like clikatell ,airtel etc.

Comment: I am unable to offer anything else given the current info. I would rather use SO for communication... And, yes, our platform is connected to hundreds of carriers all over the world.

Comment: so can you please provide me the example code how your are able to connect different gateways.

Comment: why is there any problem wahid,i don't want full code just that class which is used to connect multiple gateways just for example to follow